# Conver integer to cryptocurrency

Tags: python, python-3.x

If i have some amount of Dogecoins like:

```
amount = 212406306381
print(amount)
>>> 2124.063,063,81
```

or `200000` LTC coint to `0.002,000,00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's kind of a strange number format, isn't it? ;)

```
def myprint(a):
    print "{:01d}.{:03d},{:03d},{:02d}".format((a % 10**12) / 10**8, (a % 10**8) / 10**5, (a % 10**5) / 10**2, a % 10**2)

myprint(212406306381) # prints 2124.063,063,81
myprint(200000) # prints 0.002,000,00
```

Comment: can you convert it to Python3 like `print(" ... ".format( ...))`